# I can't understand this example about Overload Operators

Tags: python, oop, operators, overloading

I'm reading a book, and it's got this example here (about Overload Operators in Python):

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, *args):
      self.Input = args

   def __add__(self, Other):

      Output = MyClass()
      Output.Input = self.Input + Other.Input
      return Output

   def __str__(self):
      Output = ""
      for Item in self.Input:
         Output += Item
         Output += " "
      return Output

Value1 = MyClass("Red", "Green", "Blue")
Value2 = MyClass("Yellow", "Purple", "Cyan")
Value3 = Value1 + Value2

print("{0} + {1} = {2}"
      .format(Value1, Value2, Value3))
```

Just to highlight, here is the output:

```
Red Green Blue  + Yellow Purple Cyan  = Red Green Blue Yellow Purple Cyan
```

So, I know what happens here, but there's one thing that I can't understand. The Value 1 and Value 2 objects give two tuples to "*args", and then, the code put "args" in self.Input, and that's ok. But, starting at the **add** method, the argument "Other" receives the second tuple ("Yellow", "Purple", "Cyan") and this tuple was on the self.Input variable first. To prove this, you can just use the print() statement at the constructor and the **add** method, and you that there is a change in the content in the variables. If there's any Python programmer who can explain to me why does it happen, I would be glad. I'm sorry if it's not so easy to understand, because English it's not my first language.

Again, just to highlight, for example: if you put "print (self.Input)" at the **init** method, you'll be able to see that it contains the two tuples (RGB AND YPC), but, if you put "print (self.Input)" at the **add** method, it will print only the RGB tuple, and the YPC tuple will be at the "Other.Input", for some reason, that I don't know, and basically, that's my question: Why does self.Input has the two tuples at the constructor method, but, at the '**add**' method, it's doesn't anymore?

Comment: `Value1` is still RGB, `Value2` is still YPC.  Which variable's content changed?

Comment: YPC is indeed still assigned to `self.Input`, but within the `Value2` object. Once the objects `Value1` and `Value2` are added, Python's datamodel ensures that the `__add__()` function of `Value1` is called with `Value2` as the (`Other`) argument. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey MarkM, I almost got ya, but it's not clear to me yet, I'm sorry, but could you explain it with more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a `print` to the code you can see which instance is `self` and which is `other` at the time that `__add__` is executed:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args: str):
        self.input = args

    def __add__(self, other: 'MyClass'):
        print(f"Adding {self} to {other}")
        return MyClass(*(self.input + other.input))

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return " ".join(self.input)


value1 = MyClass("Red", "Green", "Blue")
value2 = MyClass("Yellow", "Purple", "Cyan")
value3 = value1 + value2

print(f"{value1} + {value2} = {value3}")
```

prints:

```
Adding Red Green Blue to Yellow Purple Cyan
Red Green Blue + Yellow Purple Cyan = Red Green Blue Yellow Purple Cyan
```

So when you call `value1 + value2`, it's the same as if you said `value1.__add__(value2)`.  The `other` argument is `value2` (which contains `Yellow Purple Cyan`), and `self` is `value1` (which contains `Red Green Blue`).

Comment: Thank you a lot mate, I'm a beginner, so I'm not acquainted to this stuff, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is exactly, but that's how `__add__` method works.
Whenever you use `+` operator, it'll call `__add__` from the left operand and
the right operand will be passed in as the argument.

So when `Value1 + Value2` is executed, python:

1. calls `__add__` method from `Value1` and `Value1` gets assigned to `self`
2. `Value2` gets passed in to the method and gets assigned to `Other` parameter.